# Isomorphic function fields of projective curves, bijection of points.

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves

Suppose curves $C$, $D \in \mathbb{CP}^2$ are nonsingular. If their function fields are isomorphic, i.e. $K_C \cong K_D$, then do we necessarily have a bijection of points on $C$ and $D$? Can we do stronger and say something like $C$ and $D$ are necessarily isomorphic as ringed spaces? How can one intuitively arise at an answer to this question?

EDIT: It would be nice if I got an answer that did not talk about birational equivalence or manifolds...

Comment: I think that you are looking for the notion of [birational equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_mapping).

Comment: Having isomorphic function fields and being birational to each other are the exact same thing — somehow as soon as you tried to turn the field isomorphism into a morphism you would discover this concept. So I don't think you're really saving yourself a lot of trouble. Transcendental methods, on the other hand, are unnecessary.

Comment: It can be shown that isomorphisms of function fields induce birational equivalence. Now we are dealing with projective and so  complete curves, and every rational map from a nonsingular curve to a complete variety can be extended to a morphism. Every nonconstant morphism between nonsingular complete curves is surjective, giving us the desired result.

Comment: These results can be found in chapter 8 of Ben Moonens algebraic geometry lecture notes avaible online at http://www.math.ru.nl/~bmoonen/teaching.html

Answer (score 4):

It can be shown that two algebraic varieties are [birationally equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_mapping) if and only if their function fields are isomorphic.

In particular, two non-singular projective curves are birationally equivalent if and only they are isomorphic. You can prove this by observing that by Serre's [GAGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_geometry_and_analytic_geometry) a non-singular projective complex curve is just a (holomorphic) compact connected complex manifold $C$ of dimension $1$. In particular, by the maximum principle you can uniquely extend a morphism defined on an open, dense subset $U$ of $C$ to the whole of $C$.

Comment: Is there a simpler way to see this without talking about birational equivalence?

Comment: I don't know, but I suspect that you can't really avoid the rational morphism induced by the function field morphism. Note, though, that in Hartshorne's book the proof of corollary I.4.5 is fairly simple and shows why two varieties are birationally equivalent if and only if their function fields are isomorphic. On the other hand, if you wish to avoid GAGA have a look at Hartshorne's section I.6, in particular corollary I.6.11 (*that*'s not really simple, though).

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain him/herself? Please note that this answer was posted before the question was edited.